# Scheduling NSStream events on an NSRunLoop that isn't the main run loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsrunloop, nsstream

I'm scheduling events on the main run loop using the following code:

```
[stream setDelegate:self];
[stream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[stream open];
```

I assume that this means that `NSStreamDelegate` events are being scheduled on the main run loop and therefore can potentially impact UI responsiveness if frequent enough. This certainly seems to be the case in my program - even if the event handlers detach into a background thread without doing much work themselves.

How would I go about scheduling on a run loop other than `mainRunLoop`? Do I need to create a thread? Can I just create an NSRunLoop directly? What setup needs to be performed?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a concurrent nsoperstion. I have a demo app on github that shows how to message such an object. You will find many such projects too. You can then use the performSelector variant that takes a thread specifier (the thread for such an operation is persistent).

The op has a run loop so can be messaged, a thread, can easily be cancelled, and you can create multiples of them.

Comment: Nice, but what about that "demo app" in github - a link would be greatly appreciated. (hmmm, at least the name of it?)

Comment: @MottiShneor the code is 3 years old now but might be of help: https://github.com/dhoerl/Concurrent_NSOperations